# Smoke have cubes in silhouette

Tags: smoke-simulation

Its very important to me. I ask your help.

I make explosion in space. Scale of domain is 600 meters. Version 2.93.4
I have cubes in smoke and this is not cool, this smoke is need use to film. How I can fix it and make smoke more beauty?
Important - it should be in EEVEE

[image: cubes in smoke lines. The particles goes very fast.]

blend file https://yadi.sk/d/wXS7WXRj7GS68A

Comment: I see that in smoke simulation you are using only 64 resolution, try to give it much higher number... resolution 64 means that there are 64*64*64 cubes of space in your domain for smoke particles, that's why your smoke looks blocky

Answer (score 1):

So as I have said, change your fluid domain resolution, that's all, all other settings are good to make it very detailed, but 64 for domain resolution is too small for final render.

I am currently on my potato PC so I cannot show you the result of higher resolution, but even this image below is 128 resolution... Try 200+ ,maybe even 300 if you have a time for that and bake it before render and hopefully it will be better
[image]

Don't judge this picture, I had to lower some of the other settings to be able to show you

Comment: Okay, but how I can safe big part of smoke? If I up resolution, parts of smoke became litlle.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, Do you mean you want the smoke to look less blocky but still big? Use higher particle size in your icosphere smoke simulation settings(probably)